# Update values in visual c++ resourcefile automatically

Tags: visual-c++, resources, resource-file

In my Visual C++ 6.0 project I have some values in the **MyProject.rc** file, like

```
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040604b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "My Project comment\0"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "My Company\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "9, 9, 1, 9\0"
            VALUE "SpecialBuild", "Release Version\0"
        END
    END
END
```

In light of wasting some time in debugging and error-finding, I want the compiler to update any value in the resource-file of my project, by inserting the value of the version of another .dll library, used by **MyProject**. 
I want to use this feature, so I can see what version of a second library **MyProject** is using.
Is there any way I can insert the value of the version of another library at compiletime, in **MyProject.rc**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a simple program which takes the dll version and edits the rc file, which can be called as pre-build-step.